# Listview BaseAdapter with Edittext and Prepoulated values does not persist

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I Have a listview with values already populated from a web service. All this works fine and as expected. The listview consists of a label and and an edittext with numeric values. This values should ideally be editable, the problem is after I edit the value and scroll the listview the number returns to the initial (Say if the initial value was 10 and I edit to say 20 and scroll the list it returns back to 10 )

The adapter is as below: How do I remedy this

```
public class Values_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> filteredData;
private Typeface lightTypeface;
int i=0;


public Values_Adapter  (Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d)
{
    activity = a;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    filteredData = d;
    arrTemp = new String [filteredData !=null ? filteredData.size() : 0];
    lightTypeface = TypefaceHelper.get(activity, "SegoeWP-Light");
}

public int getCount()
{
    return filteredData !=null ? filteredData.size() : 0;
}

public Object getItem(int position)
{
    return filteredData.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return position;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView sku_id;
    TextView sku;
    TextView tr;
    EditText sku_quantity;
    int ref;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    final ViewHolder holder;
    View vi = convertView;
    if(convertView==null){

        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_values, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.sku_id = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.lbl_sku_id);
        holder.sku_id.setTypeface(lightTypeface);
        holder.sku = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.lbl_sku);
        holder.sku.setTypeface(lightTypeface);
        holder.tr = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.lbl_tr);
        holder.tr.setTypeface(lightTypeface);
        holder.sku_quantity = (EditText)vi.findViewById(R.id.edtxt_quantity);
        holder.sku_quantity.setTypeface(lightTypeface);
        vi.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    }

    HashMap<String, String> skus = filteredData.get(position);

    holder.ref=position;
    holder.sku_id.setText( skus.get(Vs.KEY_SKU_ID));
    holder.sku.setText( skus.get(V_SKUs.KEY_SKU));
    holder.tr.setText( skus.get(V_SKUs.KEY_TR));
    holder.sku_quantity.setText(skus.get(V_SKUs.KEY_SKU_QTY));

    holder.sku_quantity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence args,int arg1,int ar2,int arg3){

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence args,int arg1,int ar2,int arg3){

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged (Editable s){

            arrTemp[holder.ref]=s.toString();
        }
    });



    return vi;

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are saving the new text inside a temp array,

```
arrTemp[holder.ref]=s.toString();
```

but you are displaying the teste from data array

```
holder.sku_quantity.setText(skus.get(V_SKUs.KEY_SKU_QTY));
```

so every time you recreate a view, you are displaying the old text, not the new edited one

you need to check if there is new data in the temp array to display, instead of the original data

Comment: Thanks that actually solved it   holder.sku_quantity.setText(arrTemp[position]!=null? arrTemp[position]:skus.get(V_SKUs.KEY_SKU_QTY));